# Coin collection 2 player game

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

Consider an array of n coins with positive integer value and two players player1 and player2. Each player takes the coins turn after turn till there are coins left. The one with the 
maximum value wins. The number of coins that a player can take is governed by a variable S initially =1, and a player can take the k coins starting from left contiguously where 1<=k
<=2*S And after a player takes say k coins the value of S becomes max(S,k). Also, there is an assumption that both players play the optimal strategy. **We have to find the maximum amount of** 
 **coin value that player 1 can take in the game** 
For example: if the input is [3,6,8,5,4], the output should be 12 because if player1 takes one coin, player 2 takes 2 coins, and then player one retakes 2 coins. So player1 
will have 3 + 5 + 4 = 12.

**My Thoughts:** I feel there could be some way to do it using dynamic programming, but I cannot find the subproblems or optimal substructure. The conditions look very complex. Any ideas on how to approach this?

Comment: If you cannot find a subproblem, what let you think that  dynamic programming is a possible/good approach?

Comment: The subproblems are defined by the coins remaining, and the value of S. For example, if player1 takes one coin the subproblem is `[6,8,5,4]` with `S=1`. But if player1 takes two coins, the subproblem is `[8,5,4]` with `S=2`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sub problem is identified by:

- The number of coins already taken. Otherwise put: the index in the coins array from where the next coins can be taken.
- The value of S.

As the number of coins that can be taken and the value of S can never exceed the number of coins , we can memoize results using a matrix of size .

The turn is not important for the memoization: no matter whose turn it is, they will have the same opportunities in the same state. So if we encounter a state for player 1 and evaluate it (maximizing the coin value), and then later encounter that same state, but with player 2 to play, then that previous result can be taken to apply to player 2.

The algorithm can use recursion. The base case occurs when the current player could decide to take all remaining coins. And of course, that would always be the best move.

For the recursive case, all possible moves for the current player can be played. For each the best score for the opponent can be derived by making the recursive call. The best move for the current player is the move where the best score for the opponent is *minimized*.

Here is an implementation in JavaScript. Running this snippet will solve the problem you presented in the question, and also [1,1,1,1,1,1,1]:

```js
function solve(coins) {
    let n = coins.length;
    // Preprocessing: for all possibly suffix arrays, calculate the sum of the coins
    let sums = coins.slice(); // copy 
    for (let i = n - 2; i >= 0; i--) {
        sums[i] += sums[i + 1]; // backwards running sum
    }

    // 2D Array for memoization (dynamic programming)
    let dp = []; // n x n matrix, initially filled with -1
    for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) dp.push(Array(n).fill(-1));

    return recur(0, 1);
    
    function recur(start, s) {
        if (n - start <= 2*s) return sums[start]; // base case: take all remaining coins
        if (dp[start][s] == -1) { // sub problem was not encountered before
            let minOpponentScore = Infinity;
            // For each possible move, get best counter move from opponent
            for (let k = 1; k <= 2*s; k++) {
                // We'll take the move where the best counter move was the worst
                minOpponentScore = Math.min(minOpponentScore, recur(start + k, Math.max(k, s)));
            }
            dp[start][s] = sums[start] - minOpponentScore;
        }
        return dp[start][s];
    }
}

console.log(solve([3,6,8,5,4]));
console.log(solve([1,1,1,1,1,1,1]));
```

Comment: that was a stroke of genius. Thanks a lot. Just curious to know a bit about you. What do you do? Are you into software development?

Comment: I started as professional software developer in the ninetees, after getting hooked to it since the mid eighties. Evolved to IT project manager.

Comment: Cool. What are your favorite software books? Which you think one must read to get an in-depth understanding of things. I am a Java developer but curious to dig deeper into things.

Comment: I cannot really recommend a book. It has been many years I last read one on software development.